# Jest and hybrid Angular/AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, angular, unit-testing, typescript, jestjs

I'm considering to use `jest` for testing my hybrid application (Angular + AngularJS). I'm using `jest-preset-angular` for Angular testing but I also need `angular-mocks` for AngularJS testing.

The problem is when I import both `jest-preset-angular` and `angular-mocks` in `setupJest.ts`, all the tests (Angular and AngularJS) fail with `Cannot read property '$injector' of null` error (coming from `angular-mocks`).

If I import just `jest-preset-angular` all the Angular tests pass, if I import just `angular-mocks` all the AngularJS tests pass.

How do I make it work together?

**package.json:**

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts"
}
```

**setupJest.ts:**

```
import 'jest-preset-angular';
import 'angular';
import 'angular-mocks';

const mock = () => {
    let storage = {};
    return {
        getItem: key => key in storage ? storage[key] : null,
        setItem: (key, value) => storage[key] = value || '',
        removeItem: key => delete storage[key],
        clear: () => storage = {},
    };
};

Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {value: mock()});
Object.defineProperty(window, 'sessionStorage', {value: mock()});
Object.defineProperty(window, 'getComputedStyle', {
    value: () => ['-webkit-appearance']
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the order matters.
Importing `angular-mocks` before `jest-preset-angular` fixes the issue:

```
import 'angular';
import 'angular-mocks';
import 'jest-preset-angular';
```